# ListView not populating via Array Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

```
public class HotelListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    HotelInfo a[] = new HotelInfo[5];

    public HotelListAdapter(Activity context, HotelInfo[] b)
    {
        super();
        this.a=b;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {       
        return 5;   //currently hardcoded to 5
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertview;

        if(convertview==null)
        {   
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);        
            TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Hname);
            TextView stname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Stname);
            name.setText(a[position].HHname);
            stname.setText(a[position].STname);
            position++;   // how to loop till 5 or x number.... ?
        }
            return vi;
    }

}
```

This is my adapter for populating the list. The list should be displaying a MAINTEXT and a small SUBTEXT. I need to populate the list with an array of objects(current array of 5 objects but want to know for 'x' length of array) ! The object contains two String fields only. Please help with the code. Thanx.

```
public class ListHotels extends ListActivity
{   

        HotelInfo[] b = new HotelInfo[5];
    void HotelInfo()
    {
        b[0].setvalues("AAA","xxx");
        b[1].setvalues("BBB","yyy");
        b[2].setvalues("CCC","zzz");
        b[3].setvalues("DDD","www");
        b[4].setvalues("EEE","ppp");        
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.listhotels);
        HotelListAdapter adapter = new HotelListAdapter(this,b);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

}
```

This is the ListActivity. No errors in code currently.

Comment: no need to write position++; . getViewMethod() will automatically calls no of time that count you returned in getCount() method.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to place `position++`,  the position will increment automatically according to the number of list items in your list. So change `return 5;` in the `getCount()` to `return a.length;`

In this manner you are future-proofing your code for a dynamically sized list.

```
@Override
public int getCount() 
{       
    return a.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these two methods to this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() 
{       
    return a.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) 
{
    return a[arg0];
}
```

And then change getView to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(convertview == null)
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);        

    HotelInfo currentInfo = (HotelInfo)getItem(position);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.Hname);
    TextView stname = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.Stname);
    name.setText(currentInfo.HHname);
    stname.setText(currentInfo.STname);
    return convertview;
}
```

Comment: no errors in code but there is some runtime error.... app was force closed in the emulator !

Comment: probably a nullpointerexception somewhere, post the logcat of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public class HotelListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    HotelInfo a[] = new HotelInfo[5];

             private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView name;
            public TextView stname;

        }

    public HotelListAdapter(Activity context, HotelInfo[] b)
    {
        super();
        this.a=b;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {       
            return a.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
         return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertview;
    final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertview==null)
        {   
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);  
            holder = new ViewHolder();  //change is here..    
            holder.name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Hname);
            holder.stname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Stname);
            vi.setTag(holder);            
        }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

            holder.name.setText(a[position].HHname);
            holder.stname.setText(a[position].STname);


            return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors at 5 places which say " The local variable holder may not have been initialized "

Comment: Error log

09-06 12:46:58.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 12:46:58.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1583): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 12:46:58.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at com.example.home_delivery_demo.HotelListAdapter.getView(HotelListAdapter.java:72)
09-06 12:46:58.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
09-06 12:46:58.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1583):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)

Comment: what is HotelListAdapter.java:72‌ line

Comment: Line 72 is

holder.name.setText(a[position].HHname);

Comment: i think a[] array is empty that why nullpointerexception.. check out a[] array having values or not...

Comment: I've written this.a = b.... so b[] must get copied into a[] right ? b[] is definitely not empty. Still how to confirm if a[] or b[] is empty or not... ?